# echo removes a blank last line from the output

Tags: bash, shell, echo, tail

I am using a script to obtain the last n-2 lines of a file using a command and then using echo to print this lines into a file.

```
last_n2_lines=`tail -n+3 $file`
echo "$last_n2_lines" >> $file
```

This echo here removes a trailing new line from the end of file. 
FYI

> tail -n+3 file > file.new

is working perfectly well.

Comment: Are you asking a question, or just noticing? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid bash command substitution to remove the newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could preserve the trailing empty lines by using `readarray` to save the data, and `printf` for output.

Something like:

```
readarray last_n2_lines < <(tail -n+3 $file)
printf "%s" "${last_n2_lines[@]}" > ${file}.new
```

Demo:

```
$ cat test; echo end 
1
2
3
4


end
$ tail -n+3 test ; echo end
3
4


end
$ readarray data < <(tail -n+3 test)
$ printf "%s" "${data[@]}" ; echo end  
3
4


end
```

Explanation:

- `readarray data` reads lines from standard input into the array called `data`.
- `cmd1 < <(cmd2 param1 param2 ...)` redirects the output of `cmd2 param1 param2 ...` to the standard input if `cmd1`. Careful with the syntax: it must be `< [space] <(...)`, no space between `<(`, space required between the two `< <`.

So after the first line, `data` contains all the lines that `tail -n+3` output. Each item in the array is a line of the input *with the line terminator included*.
Here's how you access each element. Notice that two lines are printed for each item defined in the array: the one in the array (which contains a newline), and the newline added by `echo`.

```
$ echo "${data[0]}"
3

$ echo "${data[1]}"
4

$ echo "${data[2]}"


$ echo "${data[3]}"


$ echo "${data[4]}"  # out of bounds

$
```

- `${data[@]}` expands to all elements of the array `data`
- `printf "%s" param1 param2 ...` prints all of its arguments unchanged (i.e. doesn't add or remove line terminators).

So the second statement prints back everything that was read in, unchanged.

Comment: Added a demo. Please always remember: "not working" is not a useful thing to say. Describe how it is not working.

Comment: Oh sorry for the vagueness ... Actually I was doing echo on the array variable. On trying printf it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the Manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

> 3.5.4 Command Substitution
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
> command itself. Command substitution occurs when a command is enclosed
> as follows:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the
> command, ***with any trailing newlines deleted***. Embedded newlines
> are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting. The
> command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but
> faster $(< file).
>
> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
> retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.
> The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
> substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between
> the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
>
> Command substitutions may be nested. To nest when using the backquoted
> form, escape the inner backquotes with backslashes.
>
> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and
> filename expansion are not performed on the results.

Emphasis mine. So it is not a bug. It is a feature.

Comment: how should i prevent this removal of trailing new line ?? I tried  last_n2_lines=$(tail -n +3 $file; echo -n x)
    last_n2_lines="${last_n2_lines%x}"
but this is not working

Comment: A workaround would be `echo -e "\n" >> $file` but that applies only if you know that a newline is present.